# Did Hamas leader Yahya Sinwar state he aims to remove all people from Israel?

Tags: israel, hamas

German [tagesschau](https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/asien/sinwar-hamas-100.html) quotes Israeli journalist [Ehud Yaari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehud_Yaari) about [Yahya Sinwar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahya_Sinwar), the head of Hamas in Gaza:

> Das erklärte Ziel Sinwars sei es, alle Menschen in Israel entweder zu töten oder zu vertreiben.

Meaning:

> The declared goal of Sinwar is, to either displace or kill all people in Israel.

That is more radical than the [Hamas Charter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamas_Charter), either the 1988 or the 2017 version, and also more radical than statements by senior Hamas figures, which either allow Jews to live as a minority in an Islamist Palestine, or aims to displace or kill all Jews.  Neither charter seems consistent with killing or displacing all *people* in Israel, which would include Palestinians and non-Jewish immigrants.

Perhaps Mr. Sinwar considers all Palestinians in Israel as traitors/collaborators that must be killed or displaced, but I would expect such a viewpoint to be controversial even within Hamas.

Has Mr. Sinwar publicly stated he wishes to kill or displace all people in Israel, or is there otherwise evidence this is his goal?

Comment: I suppose reasonable people could disagree on what precisely he means about "wiping out Israel": https://www.timesofisrael.com/hamas-chief-we-wont-discuss-recognizing-israel-only-wiping-it-out/ It reminds me of discussions over what Iran meant years ago about "wiping Israel off the map", or even what the slogan "from the river to the sea" actually means.

Comment: This long [BBC story](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-67473719) about Sinwar is also largely referenced with quotes from Yaari, but the claim in Q doesn't appear there, so alas it looks like we're stuck with the German version.

Comment: This question seems to be about intentions and thus off-topic for this website.

Comment: @Christian It's not about his intent.  It's about his words.

Comment: @gerrit : The source does not cite him for using specific words.

Answer (score 3):

First it should be said that the counter-claim made in the question that "[n]either charter seems consistent with killing or displacing all people in Israel, which would include Palestinians and non-Jewish immigrants", is very debatable. I will not get into a detailed analysis but I think the Wikipedia article leaves this very much in doubt. One could cherry-pick details to support this interpretation, or do the same to support the complete opposite. I will put this question aside.

As for the primary claim attributed to Yaari, it is notable that [according to *The Times of Israel*](https://www.timesofisrael.com/hamas-chief-we-wont-discuss-recognizing-israel-only-wiping-it-out/), the Hamas-affiliated [Shebab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shehab_News_Agency) outlet reported that Sinwar stated months after adoption of current 2017 Hamas charter:

> Over is the time Hamas spent discussing recognizing Israel. Now Hamas will discuss when **we will wipe out Israel**

[Shebab's website](https://shehabnews.com) appears to be offline at the moment, but I can see via Internet Archive that it is in Arabic. I hope maybe at some point someone proficient in Arabic can confirm the original quote.

Assuming the translation quoted above is accurate, it is not reasonable to interpret this as evidence of what Yaari said. However, there remains at least some room for debate here. The language of "wiping" Israel away has [a complex history with respect to Iran](https://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/fact-checker/post/did-ahmadinejad-really-say-israel-should-be-wiped-off-the-map/2011/10/04/gIQABJIKML_blog.html), a major sponsor of Hamas. Iran has claimed that wiping Israel off the map means "the defeat of Zionist ideology and the dissolution of Israel through a 'popular referendum.'" Of course, supporters of Israel will say this is patently absurd.

In conclusion, I think we have no firm conclusion, because Hamas is ambiguous in its statements. I say this with the important caveat that an Arabic speaker might debunk the key statement that seems to support Yaari's claim. In that case, I would say Yaari's claim is an overstatement of the facts, but the question's own claims about the meaning of the Hamas charter remains a separate question.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, this is at most a comment.

Comment: @Simel I have provided and discussed the best available evidence to support the claim in question.

Comment: There is a leap in this question, and I am not sure if it is fair. "Did X say Y?" "Well, X said Z, and and there is debate about whether that could possibly mean Y." Sure, but did X also say Y? (The trouble with quote questions is they are very hard to falsify.)

Comment: @oddthinking If your point is that the question should be closed, I might not object to that. There are no votes to close the question, but I am being downvoted for a good faith effort to answer it.

Comment: @Oddthinking, this is not a question about a quote, this is a question about intent, Yaari doesn't claim that Sinwar said this exact quote, but that this is his intent, as he's a prominent figure this can be verified. I would start from the original quote by Yaari and see the context to his claim, and then provide quotes that either support or disprove the claim. If there is a claim of Sinwar saying "we want to coexist with Israel" or "we will allow Jews to live in the state of Palestine as equal citizens" would be disproving this claim sayings like "we will destroy Israel" support the claim.

Comment: @simel I have provided a quote that supports the claim. I agree that if someone has a quote that contradicts the claim, they should provide it. I have pointed out that despite what the OP says, the charter does not contradict the claim. My answer isn't valid because it doesn't comprehensively evaluate every potentially relevant statement available?

Comment: @SIMEL: yeah, but Qs about intent are even more closeable here. "erklärte Ziel" is not clearly about intent though. It's possible that was mistranslated in German, which *would* be an answer though.

Comment: @SIMEL: To Fizz's point, if this *is* a question about intent, I would close it in a heartbeat. My German isn't good enough to fully understand the claim, but the translation suggests that Yaari says that Sinwar explicitly stated this was his [Sinwar's] goal. If Yaari doesn't mean that Sinwar said that explicitly, we should close.

Comment: @BrianZ: What is your argument for the question being closed? I don't doubt your good faith, but I am pointing out a flaw - you haven't shown he didn't say it.

Comment: @oddthinking I just meant to point out that your first comment on my answer was fundamentally a complaint about the nature of the question being asked, not my answer to it. My answer shows evidence that Sinwar may have said something that more-or-less directly implies the intent attributed to him in the primary claim.

Comment: @BrianZ: Oh, I am sorry. I meant to write "There is a leap in this **answer**, and I am not sure if it is fair. " I apologise for causing this confusion.